# Prime Sum of Arithmetic Sequence

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

Apologies for the formatting, I'm not well-versed in math and I'm unfamiliar with the styles used here.
I was wondering, is there any arithmetic sequence with at least three terms and a common difference of one that the sum is prime? I've been doodling on a white board trying to figure this out, I appreciate any reply or hint in the right direction!

Edit: I shouldn't of left it to be implied, but the arithmetic progression should only consist of natural numbers!

Answer (score 0):

$$
a + (a+1) + (a+2) + \cdots + (a+n) = \frac{(n+1)(a+b)}{2}
$$
so it won't be prime.

(To see that, write the sum in reverse order and add term by term.)

(But good for you for doodling around with mathematics.)

Comment: Weirdly enough, I've been working with trapezoids because I found that end pattern. That's a cool coincidence!

Comment: other condition that help disable it are any such arithmetic progression needs an odd number of odd terms